# How do I list and kill all running jobs of a multibranch pipeline from the jenkins script console

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

due to config errors or other problems sometimes I just want to abort ALL jobs of a single multibranch pipeline.

How can I do this from the script console?

I can call doKill() on a job object but how do I iterate over a list of all jobs of a multibranch pipeline and kill all of them?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the script I use to abort all running builds. You could adapt it to check the name of the build before canceling it with some condition like `job.name ==~ /myjob/`

```
import jenkins.model.*

// remove jobs in queu
def queue = Jenkins.instance.queue
println "Queue contains ${queue.items.length} items"
queue.clear()
println 'Queue cleared.'

// Cancel running builds
def numCancels = 0
for (job in Jenkins.instance.items) {
  if (job.hasProperty('builds')) {
    for (build in job.builds) {
      if (build.isBuilding()) {
            println "Stopping ${build.toString()}"
            build.doStop();
            println "${build.toString()} stopped."
            numCancels++
        }
    }
  }
}
println "${numCancels} Jobs canceled."
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!